# Passing JavaScript Data onClick()

Tags: javascript, html

Hope Everyone is doing good.

I want to pass data on button click. This is my code, I am not getting it on other side.

```js
<script>
    function submit() {
      var url =  "http://localhost:8080" + "/submit"
      var data = {"order":"Full"};
      $.post(url, {},  
        function(data, status, xhr) {
          alert('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        'json'
      );
    }
  </script>
```

```html
<button onClick="submit()">submit</button>
```

Comment: If the button is in a form, the form is submitted and the XHR call is aborted. I assume you have some data in the currently empty object? It's notable, that you can't send an empty object, because everything is passed as string.

Comment: second argument should be `data`, But you are passing as `{}`. thats why you are not getting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try below with ajax function

```
var oParameters = {
                attributeValue : 'myAttributeValue',
                attributeType: 'myAttributeType'
           };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080" + "/submit",
            type: "POST",
            data: oParameters,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Data submitted successfully....");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Error while submitting Data");
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
Can I take this value on backend(Python)?
I am not sending it inside a form.

Comment: yes... though I have not much idea about python but if it is properly configured on backend side you will get value in backend for sure

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an empty object as the data of the POST request. Change the `$.post` call to this.

```
$.post(url, data,
  function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  'json'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. BTW Can I receive these data on backend . I am using Python.